# flutter: Variable can't be used as a setter because it's final

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List<TestModel> lists = List();

FutureBuilder<List<TestModel>>(
          future: testNetworkRepository.fetchAlltext(TestModel.testKey),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              lists = snapshot.data;
              return Contanier();
            }
          }
)

Future _editText(int index, String testKey) async {
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: SimpleDialog(
          children: [
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: TextButton(
                    child: Text("Edit"),
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        lists[index].text = editTextController.text; <- error occured
                      });
                    },
                  ),
            )
          ],
        )
    );
  }
```

This is my code. I want to edit `lists[index].text`.

But error occured.

> 'text' can't be used as a setter because it's final.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error happened because the text property of the TestModel class is final.
Final objects arent meant to be changed in Flutter.
to fix this problem you should go to the TestModel class and remove final from the text property.

Comment: I get this error after removing final : `Can't define a const constructor for a class with non-final fields.`

Answer (score 1):

Go in data class model change it like below:

```
static late List<item> items
```

if they not working then remove `final` keyword.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Tomerikoo what do I do if the class is part of a library like Google Maps?  trying to update  icon value of a a map Marker

Answer (score 1):

State parameters are immutable, but what you can do is to call it with the `copyWith()` method.
The `copyWith()` method, returns a new State. It means that we cannot change the state but make the changes to the current one and assign it to a new one. with every change a new state will be returned.